# Is there a better way to structure this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, run-on-sentence

I am having a hard time re-working the following sentence. I know it gets pretty heavy near the middle of the sentence. At this part:
`design experts utilizing a diverse`.

Would a simple comma before `utilizing` be all the sentence needs or is there a better way to structure it?

> Your imagination is the only limiting factor when combining NEXT-LEVEL
>   DESIGN with MB Kit design experts utilizing a diverse collection of
>   aluminum profiles and components.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: It's not immediately clear who's doing the utilizing or really what exactly one is to combine with next-level design.

Comment: @KarlG the "MB Kit design experts" are utilizing. All three compinents: design experts, product (diverse collection of ....), and next-level design all form together to make the project.

Comment: @KarlG I added the entire page this text is on. The page on the left includes the text in my question.

Comment: Then just write _experts, who use_. _Constant momentum load situation_ is clunky beyond repair, and while in the first sentence my imagination is the only limiting factor, I discover there are, however, _limiting factors_. It sounds like you're apologizing for gravity.

Comment: @KarlG Would it make the most sense to write it like this? `Your imagination is the only limiting factor when combining NEXT-LEVEL DESIGN with MB Kit design experts and diverse collection of aluminum profiles and components.`

Comment: The limiting factors are the traditional fastening technology. Incorporating next-level design is what makes the design options endless.

Comment: I agree the constant momentum load sentence is pretty bad. What would you do for that sentence? `Projects that require high-loads must sustain strong vibrations or applications which are under constant momentum load situations require additional bracing.`

Comment: Is this better? `Your imagination is the only limiting factor when combining MB Kit design experts, using an extensive product collection, with NEXT-LEVEL Design.`

Comment: You seem to be wed to the idea of using participles with unclear antecedents. In that last sentence, I am the one combining, so I'm going to assume I'm the one using as well, until I reach my WTF moment with _with NEXT-LEVEL design_. And what's with the hyphen? You don't say _I have a black-cat_. I also don't know why I need to know about the additional bracing at this point, but I would say _Projects exposed to strong vibration or a constant momentum load require additional bracing._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be better but your the one getting paid

Your imagination does not need to be a limiting factor, combine
MB Kit's NEXT-LEVEL DESIGN experts using "no-cost" engineering
with a diverse collection of aluminum profiles and components.

Design options are endless with MB Kit Systems’ NEXT-LEVEL DESIGN. Modular T-slot products provide a strong basis for application design, however there are limiting factors for more advanced projects that require strong stability and design flexibility. Examples include "high-load" projects that must sustain strong vibrations or applications under constant momentum load situations may require additional bracing.

Next-Level Design increases a project’s level of integrity, ultimately enabling higher-level build quality for most situations. Enhanced design options include, but are not limited to specialty engineered braces, brackets, spacers, adapter and connecting plates created from a variety of materials such as aluminum, plastics and compounded materials.

Comment: I like what you did with paragraph two and three. Does this also work for the initial sentence? `Your imagination is the only limiting factor when combining MB Kit design experts, using an extensive product collection, with NEXT-LEVEL Design.`